# Html file is not generated in JMeter report in non GUI mode

Tags: jmeter, performance

I run my test plan in non GUI mode and it executed successfully, however it was only the csv report that got generated while the html report wasn't generated in the specified folder. this is my folder directory in cmd:

```
jmeter -n -t C:\Users\Documents\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin\creditLimitOp1.jmx -l C:\Users\Documents\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin\report\crdlimit.csv -e -o C:\Users\Documents\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin\report
```

Comment: I am having exactly same issue. Though the folder where I like to have .csv file and HTML report generated is empty. Still I am not able to generate HTML Report. The .csv file is generated but no HTML

Answer (score 2):

JMeter **cannot generate HTML Report in a non-empty folder**, consider storing .jtl file in one place and the dashboard in another. You can [copy](https://www.windows-commandline.com/windows-copy-command-syntax-examples/) the .jtl file to report folder once dashboard generation is completed.

Also consider adding [`-f` argument to your command line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) so JMeter could overwrite the results file if it exists (it might be another cause for your problem)

The final command line would be something like:

```
jmeter -n -t -f C:\Users\Documents\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin\creditLimitOp1.jmx -l C:\Users\Documents\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin\crdlimit.csv -e -o C:\Users\Documents\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin\report && copy C:\Users\Documents\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin\crdlimit.csv C:\Users\Documents\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin\report
```

Another way of viewing your test result in a fancy HTML version is using [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/) service